# OpenPGP.JS: Error while decrypting a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, openpgp.js

I try to decrypt a message by using OpenPGP.JS.
I always get this Error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Error decrypting   
message: No symmetrically encrypted session key packet found.
```

This is my code:

```
var openpgp = require('openpgp'); 
openpgp.initWorker({ path:'../node_modules/openpgp/dist/openpgp.worker.js' }) 
var passphrase = 'Our secret approach'; //what the privKey is encrypted with

const fs = require('fs'); 
var data = fs.readFileSync('./order-file.txt', 'utf8');
var pubkey = fs.readFileSync('./public.key', 'utf8');
var privkey = fs.readFileSync('./privat.key', 'utf8');

var privKeyObj = openpgp.key.readArmored(privkey).keys[0];

options = {
        message: openpgp.message.readArmored(data),     // parse armored message
        publicKeys: openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey),    // for verification (optional)
        privateKeys: openpgp.key.readArmored(privkey).keys[0].decrypt(passphrase),
        password : passphrase
    };

openpgp.decrypt(options).then(function(plaintext) {

    console.dir(plaintext);
    return plaintext.data; // 'Hello, World!'
});
```

I wonder want I'm doing wrong.
Maybe somebody has an idea.
Kind regards

Markus

Comment: is the filename where your privKey is stored definitely `privat.key` and not `private.key`?

Comment: Yes it is privat.key (I'm german). So all files are read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message form the dev: "Stop passing the passphrase in the decryption options object. That is for messages encrypted with a password (symmetric key encryption) not public key encryption, which you are using. Because you are supplying a password it thinks it's using the former mode."